# Pyautogui write() inputs gibberish

Tags: python, pyautogui

I have a few links stored as a strings in a few variables likeso:

```
linkA = "https://www.google.com"
pyautogui.write(linkA)
```

The problem is, instead of writing the contents of linkA as they are, the code sometimes decides to type "://../////." or "q//../////." instead.

If i restart the program a few times, it eventually starts working correctly. Sometimes it doesn't bug out at all.

What could be the cause?